# if public properties breaks encapsulation concept, why do they exist?

Tags: oop

There are two common [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)#Meaning) of encapsulation:

- A language mechanism for restricting direct access to some of the
  object's components.
- A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with
  the methods (or other functions) operating on that data.

Common practice is never to use public properties but use getters/setters instead. If public properties break encapsulation, why modern programming languages provide the possibility to use them?

Comment: I can think of a few although they don't apply to all languages. 1. They dont completely destroy encapsulation (you could include debug code or side effects in your getters/setters). 2. For some languages, it would be extremely hard to know what a setter/getter is through static analysis. 3. Many languages are to some extent multi paradigm. 4. Sometimes respecting encapsulation just isn't desirable - when writing small programs for example. 5. Getters/Setters are different things, they both reduce encapsulation. But a getter by value still won't allow you to modify the source object.

Comment: You are mixing public fields with public properties. Public properties ARE "language mechanism for restricting direct access to some of the object's components". Some languages don't have concept of properties and the only mechanism they have is using getters/setters. Properties are more advanced mechanism for achieving encapsulation, they can be backed with getters/setters, but they don't have to be - main difference between using properties backed by fields and fields is that you can add getters/setters to property without breaking public API.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that public fields in older languages like Java are transparent, in the sense that an expression `obj.field` *always* gets the value of the field and does nothing else, and `obj.field = value` *always* assigns a value to the field and does nothing else. Modern languages often have mechanisms to allow these syntactical forms to be overridden, so that the syntax for field access or assignment can have user-defined behaviour. That means a class can expose a field publicly without making any guarantees about its own implementation, so that properties in these languages do *not* violate encapsulation. (Technically, this is the difference between a **field** and a **property**, and you should say that public **fields** violate encapsulation but public **properties** don't.)

A few other reasons:

- Encapsulation is an object-oriented design principle, but most modern languages are not strictly object-oriented. Modern languages are typically multi-paradigm, and don't force the programmer to adopt a particular paradigm.
- Encapsulation has benefits which should be weighed against the benefits of violating encapsulation in some circumstances. For example, Java has reflection, which *absolutely* violates encapsulation; but reflection is very useful for things like serialisation or object-relational mapping.
- One of the main benefits of encapsulation is that by making each class responsible for preserving its own [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)#Invariants_in_computer_science), all of the code which has that responsibility is in one place and it's easier to make sure that the invariant is preserved. Exposing *immutable* fields doesn't violate encapsulation in this sense, because merely accessing a field can't break a class's invariant; and if literally every possible value for a field is acceptable by the invariant then arguably exposing a mutable field doesn't violate encapsulation in this sense either.